# Validation Error Placement Issue

Tags: jquery

I m using this Plugin for enabling Search Option in Select Tag
[Chosen Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

But I m facing Issue When I Validate the Page .. It place Error on Top of the Select Control and The Error Look Like this

[image]

Inspect Element

[image]

```js
$('.chosen-select').chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 10,
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
    search_contains: true,
    width: "95%"
}).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Please Suggest me How I can fix this issue

Thanks

Comment: So what is your desired position of the validation text?

Comment: I want to display error "after the Control" as in above case error should be seen after the <Select option> tag